# finding out the library of DSNUTILB utility program in JCL

Tags: mainframe, jcl

I'm having trouble with the library of DSNUTILB. I dont know what library it belongs to. I've been surfing the net but can't seem to find the answer to this. Can anyone help out? How to find the library? Thanks.

Comment: We can't know. It depends on your site's naming conventions. Ask your colleagues or your support group.

Answer (score 0):

DSNUTILB is delivered by default in the SDSNLOAD dataset by IBM. Look in the appropriate SDSNLOAD dataset that is allocated by your DB2 subsystem.